# How to simulate scenario using selenium wherein User needs to upload a excel file?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I want to replicate a scenario in which User clicks on 'Choose file' and then uploads an excel file lying on the same desktop and then clicks on submit.

I have tried using sikuli and added the below mentioned lines for file upload in the code:

```
    Pattern name = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\delhivery\\Desktop\\Selenium Class\\name.png");
    Pattern open = new Pattern("C:\\Users\\delhivery\\Desktop\\Selenium Class\\open.png");      
    Screen.src = new Screen();
    src.setAutoWaitTimeout(30);
    src.type(name, "C:\\Users\\delhivery\\Desktop\\Express CSV Files\\DataE.xlsx");
    src.click(open);
```

But still it shows errors. I have added the Sikuli Jar file as well in the project. Do I need to import something as well?

Step by step detailed instructions would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Why do yo re-use a question to ask something new? I understand it is related, but its a new question. Namely Sikuli gives errors. Also you did not include the error.

Comment: The linked page does not suggest to use Sikuli to handle this, although it should work, i think it is the worst pick of the possible solutions. Mainly because its not cross-platform and it might break with Operating System updates, because the style might change slightly, meaning you need to update the images.